# Need help resolving and understanding a few errors in mongodb using Pycharm

Tags: python, mongodb, pycharm, pymongo

I am learning python 3.0 and using it with mongodb to try and make a blog, as being instructed by an udemy tutorial. However, even though I did exactly as shown in the video, I'm not getting the correct result. My python code is:

```
import pymongo

uri="mongodb://127.0.0.1:56752"

client=pymongo.MongoClient(uri)

database=client["fullstack"]

collections=database["student"]

student=collections.find({})

for i in student:

    print(i)
```

I have checked the current port number, which is matching with the mongod terminal:

```
2017-03-30T04:57:31.250+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56752 #1 (1 connection now open)
2017-03-30T04:57:31.251+0530 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:56752 conn1: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.4.2" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "Mac OS X", architecture: "x86_64", version: "16.4.0" } }
```

However, on running the code, its showing a few errors as in:

```
/Users/suprateem/Documents/Pycharm/venv/bin/python /Users/suprateem/PycharmProjects/terminal_blog/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/suprateem/PycharmProjects/terminal_blog/app.py", line 9, in <module>
    for i in student:
  File "/Users/suprateem/Documents/Pycharm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1114, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/Users/suprateem/Documents/Pycharm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1036, in _refresh
    self.__collation))
  File "/Users/suprateem/Documents/Pycharm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 873, in __send_message
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/suprateem/Documents/Pycharm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 888, in _send_message_with_response
    server = topology.select_server(selector)
  File "/Users/suprateem/Documents/Pycharm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 214, in select_server
    address))
  File "/Users/suprateem/Documents/Pycharm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 189, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 127.0.0.1:56752: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In the tutorial, the local database we had created earlier is being shown, ie the json type structures.
So far, the differences I've faced from the tutorial is:

1. I had to use sudo mongod to run it properly, while they used mongod
2. I had to use sudo killall -15 to kill the mongod processes when launching a new terminal after closing my last mongod tab
3. I'm using a updated version of pymongo than the one in the video

Any help would be highly appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect to mongodb://127.0.0.1 with no port number - MongoDB is listening on the default port, 27017. The port you see in the log, 56752, is the client temporary port you connected from, ignore it.